# Why a lot of junk information by gem,rails and bundle under rvm?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

```
$rvm -v

rvm 1.21.15 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]


$which gem
/Users/ad9075/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem


$rvm -v

rvm 1.21.15 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

The `/Users/ad9075/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem` file is like this:

```
#!/Users/ad9075/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
#--
# Copyright 2006 by Chad Fowler, Rich Kilmer, Jim Weirich and others.
# All rights reserved.
# See LICENSE.txt for permissions.
#++

require 'rubygems'
require 'rubygems/gem_runner'
require 'rubygems/exceptions'

required_version = Gem::Requirement.new ">= 1.8.7"

unless required_version.satisfied_by? Gem.ruby_version then
  abort "Expected Ruby Version #{required_version}, is #{Gem.ruby_version}"
end

args = ARGV.clone

begin
  Gem::GemRunner.new.run args
rescue Gem::SystemExitException => e
  exit e.exit_code
end
```

When I type in gem, the output is like this:

```
$gem
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.9.2
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.9.2
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.9.3
= 4.0.0
~> 2.5.3
>= 0
>= 1.9.3
= 4.0.0
~> 3.1.0
~> 1.5.2
~> 0.6.2
~> 2.7.0
= 4.0.0
~> 0.3.37
>= 0
>= 1.9.3
= 4.0.0
~> 3.1.0
>= 0
>= 1.9.3
= 4.0.0
= 4.0.0
~> 4.0.0
~> 1.0.2
>= 0
>= 3
< 5
>= 4.0.0.beta
~> 1.3
>= 0
>= 1.9.3
>= 0.6.4
~> 0.6
~> 1.3
~> 0.3.37
~> 4.2
~> 0.1
>= 0
~> 4.4
~> 4.0
~> 3.5
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.3.5
>= 3.0.0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
~> 1.16
~> 1.4.8
>= 1.0.3
> 0.8.7
~> 2.12.0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 2.0.4
~> 4.7
~> 4.0
~> 1.2
~> 1.0
~> 1.1
~> 1.5
~> 1.0
~> 1.2
~> 1.5
~> 10.0
~> 3.6
>= 1.3.5
~> 1.0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.0
>= 1.8.11
>= 1.9.3
= 4.0.0
= 4.0.0
= 4.0.0
= 4.0.0
= 4.0.0
< 2.0
>= 1.3.0
~> 2.0.0
>= 0
>= 1.9.3
= 4.0.0
= 4.0.0
>= 0.8.7
< 2.0
>= 0.18.1
>= 0
~> 1.2
~> 1.0
~> 1.0
!= 1.3.0
~> 1.1
>= 0
~> 2.0
~> 1.2
~> 1.0
~> 1.0
~> 1.0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
~> 3.1
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
~> 2.8
>= 3.0
>= 3.0
>= 0
>= 1.3.6
~> 1.0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0.1.0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 2.2.11
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
~> 0.5.0
~> 1.0
>= 2.0.0
>= 0
>= 0.3.1
>= 0
>= 1.3.6
>= 1.8.7
~> 0.7.3
~> 2.11
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.3.2
>= 1.8.6
~> 2.1
>= 0
>= 1.0.1
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.8.7
~> 1.2
>= 1.2.1

RubyGems is a sophisticated package manager for Ruby.  This is a
basic help message containing pointers to more information.

  Usage:
    gem -h/--help
    gem -v/--version
    gem command [arguments...] [options...]

  Examples:
    gem install rake
    gem list --local
    gem build package.gemspec
    gem help install

  Further help:
    gem help commands            list all 'gem' commands
    gem help examples            show some examples of usage
    gem help platforms           show information about platforms
    gem help <COMMAND>           show help on COMMAND
                                   (e.g. 'gem help install')
    gem server                   present a web page at
                                 http://localhost:8808/
                                 with info about installed gems
  Further information:
    http://guides.rubygems.org
```

Not only gem, `rails` and `bundle` also prints out lots of junk information:

```
$rails
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.9.2
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.9.2
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.9.3
= 4.0.0
~> 2.5.3
>= 0
>= 1.9.3
= 4.0.0
~> 3.1.0
~> 1.5.2
~> 0.6.2
~> 2.7.0
= 4.0.0
~> 0.3.37
>= 0
>= 1.9.3
= 4.0.0
~> 3.1.0
>= 0
>= 1.9.3
= 4.0.0
= 4.0.0
~> 4.0.0
~> 1.0.2
>= 0
>= 3
< 5
>= 4.0.0.beta
~> 1.3
>= 0
>= 1.9.3
>= 0.6.4
~> 0.6
~> 1.3
~> 0.3.37
~> 4.2
~> 0.1
>= 0
~> 4.4
~> 4.0
~> 3.5
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.3.5
>= 3.0.0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
~> 1.16
~> 1.4.8
>= 1.0.3
> 0.8.7
~> 2.12.0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 2.0.4
~> 4.7
~> 4.0
~> 1.2
~> 1.0
~> 1.1
~> 1.5
~> 1.0
~> 1.2
~> 1.5
~> 10.0
~> 3.6
>= 1.3.5
~> 1.0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.0
>= 1.8.11
>= 1.9.3
= 4.0.0
= 4.0.0
= 4.0.0
= 4.0.0
= 4.0.0
< 2.0
>= 1.3.0
~> 2.0.0
>= 0
>= 1.9.3
= 4.0.0
= 4.0.0
>= 0.8.7
< 2.0
>= 0.18.1
>= 0
~> 1.2
~> 1.0
~> 1.0
!= 1.3.0
~> 1.1
>= 0
~> 2.0
~> 1.2
~> 1.0
~> 1.0
~> 1.0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
~> 3.1
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
~> 2.8
>= 3.0
>= 3.0
>= 0
>= 1.3.6
~> 1.0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0.1.0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 2.2.11
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
~> 0.5.0
~> 1.0
>= 2.0.0
>= 0
>= 0.3.1
>= 0
>= 1.3.6
>= 1.8.7
~> 0.7.3
~> 2.11
>= 0
>= 0
>= 1.3.2
>= 1.8.6
~> 2.1
>= 0
>= 1.0.1
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
>= 0
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

It seems that there are some junk information about version. Is it normal? Does anyone have ideas about this...

Comment: run `ruby -dwS gem` and add the output to the question

Comment: No, this is not normal. When you type in `gem`, normally you should see a summary of all the `gem` commands.